# UWP in JetBrains Rider

Tags: c#, uwp, rider

UWP doesn't work in JetBrains Rider. Returns code 1 when I run it

Errors in Package.appxmanifest:

```
URI is not registered (Settings | Languages & Frameworks | Schemas and DTDs)
```

for

```
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifest/foundation/windows10"
xmlns:mp="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/2014/phone/manifest"
xmlns:uap="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifest/uap/windows10"
```

Tried to create a project in Rider.
I downloaded VisualStudio and tried to create a project in it. In VisualStudio it runs, but in Rider it doesn't run